# Simulator or Emulator? What is the difference?

Tags: terminology, simulation, emulation

While I understand what simulation and emulation mean in general, I almost always get confused about them. Assume that I create a piece of software that mimics existing hardware/software, what should I call it? A simulator or an emulator?

Could anyone explain the difference in terms of programming?

Bonus: What is the difference in English between these two terms? (Sorry, I am not a native speaker :))

Comment: In mobile apps development, iPhone has a simulator while Android has an emulator. More here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544588/difference-between-iphone-simulator-and-android-emulator

Comment: I found Wikipedia's take on this informative: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator#Emulation_versus_simulation

Comment: this is also could be helpful in explaining this:

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/134746/whats-the-difference-between-simulation-and-emulation?newreg=f4c51f8411974305a89637a60047d35e

Answer (score 536, accepted):

Emulation is the process of mimicking the outwardly observable behavior to match an existing target.  The internal state of the emulation mechanism does not have to accurately reflect the internal state of the target which it is emulating.

Simulation, on the other hand, involves modeling the underlying state of the target.  The end result of a good simulation is that the simulation model will emulate the target which it is simulating.

Ideally, you should be able to look into the simulation and observe properties that you would also see if you looked into the original target.  In practice, there may some shortcuts to the simulation for performance reasons -- that is, some internal aspects of the simulation may actually be an emulation.

MAME is an arcade game emulator; Hyperterm is a (not very good) terminal emulator.  There's no need to model the arcade machine or a terminal in detail to get the desired emulated behavior.

Flight Simulator is a simulator; SPICE is an electronics simulator.  They model as much as possible every detail of the target to represent what the target does in reality.

EDIT: Other responses have pointed out that the goal of an emulation is to able to substitute for the object it is emulating.  That's an important point.  A simulation's focus is more on the modeling of the internal state of the target -- and the simulation does not necessarily lead to emulation.  In particular, a simulation may run far slower than real-time.  SPICE, for example, cannot substitute for an actual electronics circuit (even if assuming there was some kind of magical device that perfectly interfaces electrical circuits to a SPICE simulation.)
A simulation does not always lead to emulation --

Comment: By this definition, is it therefore impossible to *simulate* the real world in software? I don't think we can accurately represent the underlying state of the real world - only emulate observable properties... for now.

Comment: I do not agree with this _"[Simulations] model as much as possible every detail of the target to represent what the target does in reality."_ Simulations have the model of the target system with sufficient detail based on the purpose of the simulation. For instance, Flight Simulator probably does not model fishes in the sea because it is useless for the purpose of the simulation.

Comment: I think this answer makes the differentiation between the two more confusing as @Toybuilder uses the verb emulating in the definition of simulation. In the literature, emulation is often used in the context of (partly) replacement of the real system. It means, emulation operates in the real world setting not within the simulation.

Comment: Exactly the opposite answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174638/whats-the-difference-between-emulation-and-simulation

Comment: It seems that most people use these words the other way, as in: simulation generally happens on a higher level than emulation (notwithstanding that both words are rarely used together in a given context). See for example the Android Emulator versus Apple's Simulator. I propose switching around the words in this answer to stay consistent with the majority of definitions, and to prevent confusion for future visitors.

Comment: @aviator: no, the android emulator is an emulator under these definitions (it only appears to be an android phone, but internally it is not), while the iphone simulator actually simulates the complete hardware and internals of an iphone that an app has access to.  There is no higher/lower level for emulation versus simulation, it is simply a matter of what the internals look like.

Comment: "A simulation Simulation does not always lead to emulation" what do you mean by this?

Comment: @aviator, nah, the term emulation referring to "high level mimicking" is even MORE common in this context so it comes to reason simulation can only mean something else. In general pure emulation is synonymous to "high level emulation" and simulation is more closely related to what is called pure "low level emulation" in that context.

Comment: I think this answer switched the 2 terms. All other sources explain it as: simulation = duplicate behavior; emulation = duplicate inner workings. Which leads to following conclusion: they are both freaking SUBJECTIVE terms.

Comment: Although, usually emulators actually emulate hardware and can run native apps, while simulators (iPhone Simulator) require a specially built apps. Or put another way: simulator < emulator. Or: emulator is always a simulator, but simulator is not always an emulator.

Comment: Sources please? and is this really followed by industry uniformly, or does each industry have their own definition. As pointed out above, I've seen the exact opposite of this def

Answer (score 419):

**If a flight-simulator could transport you from A to B then it would be a flight-emulator.**

An emulator can replace the original for *real* use.
A Virtual PC emulates a PC.

A simulator is a model for study and analysis.

An emulator will always have to operate close to real-time. For a simulator that is not always the case. A geological simulation could do 1000 years/second or more.

Comment: @Henk Your "cockpit" example is fantastic though I understood it after I read Toybuilder answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Virtual PC *does not* emulate, it virtualizes. QEmu, on the other hand, *does* emulate. In both cases, the name should be a hint.

Comment: I think it would be safe to say that Virtual PC emulates a PC.  HOW it emulates the PC is through virtualisation, but that's more of an implementation detail.  You might argue that hardware virtualisation is a superset of emulation, in that can provide accelerated CPU support, exclusive hardware device access, etc.

Comment: Wait, doesn't Virtual PC provide a pretty much 1:1 replica of a real PC? (I mean, system virtualization in general should not only simulate external behavior but pretty much every nook and cranny of a system, unlike application virtualization where e.g., network stack is not recreated).

Comment: I think this is one of the best answers except confining the purpose of the simulator to analysis-only. Simulation has different purposes including training, experimenting, aiding understanding, optimizing etc..

Comment: Where can I find said flight emulator?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Virtual PC, at least originally, was an emulator.  It could create the appearance of an x86 PC on a PPC, which is obviously not a virtualization exercise.  To the extent that *both* Qemu and Virtual PC support virtualization, those functions are completely separate from their emulation functions.  Neither is a simulator.

Comment: I had to edit this answer to emphasize this line because it made it so clear: "If a flight-simulator could transport you from A to B then it would be a flight-emulator."

Comment: I understand what you mean @LeeB but in the context of an "emulator vs simulator" discussion I would say hardware virtualization is a particular case of emulation hence the set of "virtualizers"  is a _subset_ of the grander set of all emulators :-)

Answer (score 219):

Simulation = For *analysis* and *study*

Emulation = For usage as a *substitute*

A simulator is an environment which models but an emulator is one that replicates the usage as on the original device or system.

Simulator mimics the activity of something that it is simulating. It "appears"(a lot can go with this "appears", depending on the context) to be the same as the thing being simulated. For example the flight simulator "appears" to be a real flight to the user, although it does not transport you from one place to another.

Emulator, on the other hand, *actually "**does**"* what the thing being emulated does, and in doing so it too "*appears to be doing the same thing*". An emulator may use different set of protocols for mimicking the thing being emulated, but the result/outcome is always the same as the original object. For example, EMU8086 emulates the 8086 microprocessor on your computer, which obviously is not running on 8086 (= *different protocols*), but the output it gives is what a real 8086 would give.

Comment: Clearest answer I've seen. For me, could only be improved by omitting the extra sentence or integrating it into your excellent contrasting definitions :-D

Comment: Fully agreed. It could be more formal by saying that an emulator requires the same interface and behavior of the emulated entity, a simulator doesn't. It's the same as "usage as substitute", but more formally testable.

Answer (score 44):

It's a difference in focus. Emulators<sup>[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator)</sup> focus on recreating the behavior of a system, with no regard for how the system functions internally. Simulators<sup>[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_simulation)</sup> focus on modeling the components of a system. You use an emulator when you care mostly about what a system does, and a simulator when you care about how it does it.

As for their general English meanings, emulation is "the endeavor to equal or to excel another in qualities or **actions**", while simulation is "to **model**, replicate, duplicate the behavior, appearance or properties of". Not much difference. Emulation comes from *æmulus*, "striving, rivaling," and is related to "imitate" and "image," which suggests a surface-lever resemblance. "Simulation" comes from *similis* "like", as does the word "similar," which perhaps suggests a deeper congruence.

References:

1. Wikipedia: [Emulator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator)
2. Wikipedia: [Computer Simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_simulation)
3. Wiktionary: [emulation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/emulation)
4. Wiktionary: [simulation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/simulation)
5. Etymology Online: [emulation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=emulation&searchmode=term)
6. Etymology Online: [simulation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=simulation&searchmode=term)

Comment: Your answer is different from others. Is Virtual PC a simulator or an Emulator according to you ?

Comment: @MikaëlMayer: Many of the answers are different than the others', with only some similar. I'd consider my answer equivalent (in that things would be classified the same way) to Toybuilder and cdiggens's, and compatible with Jörg's. It's contrary only to Pontus and Aeolai's.

Comment: @MikaëlMayer Virtual PC is an emulator. It can do every thing what a real PC can do.

Comment: @Pri See the answer of this thread concerning Virtual PC. It's both, it depends from the perspective. For example you can still say it's a simulation because it cannot heat as a real computer does.

Comment: Thank you for coming back @MikaëlMayer , but to be honest, some times we cannot actually differentiate if a system is emulator or simulator. A good range of debate starts. Hope i am right! Few derive the difference based on usage, its english meaning, functionality, affordability. But when i apply all the answers in my case study, its not an easy thing

Comment: This is the most concise and correct answer in my opinion. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

I don't think emulator and simulator can be compared. Both mimic something, but are not part of the same scope of reasonning, they are not used in the same context.

In short: an emulator is designed to copy some features of the orginial and can even replace it in the real environment. A simulator is not desgined to copy the features of the original, but only to appear similar to the original to human beings. Without the features of the orginal, the simulator cannot replace it in the real environment.

An **emulator** is a device that mimics something close enough so that it **can be substituted to the real thing**. E.g you want a circuit to work like a ROM (read only memory) circuit, but also wants to adjust the content until it is what you want. You'll use a ROM emulator, a black box (likely to be CPU-based) with a physical and electrical interfaces compatible with the ROM you want to emulate. The emulator will be plugged into the device in place of the real ROM. The motherboard will not see any difference when working, but you will be able to change the emulated-ROM content easily. Said otherwise the emulator will act exactly as the actual thing in its motherboard context (maybe a little bit slower due to actual internal model) but there will be additional functions (like re-writing) visible only to the designer, out of the motherboard context. So emulator definition would be: something that mimic the original, has all of its functional features, can actually replace it to some extend in the real world, and may have additional features not visible in the normal context.

A **simulator** is used in another thinking context, e.g a plane simulator, a car simulator, etc. The simulation will take care only of some aspect of the actual thing, usually those related to **how a human being will perceive and control it**. The simulator will not perform the functions of the real stuff, and cannot be sustituted to it. The plane simulator will not fly or carry someone, it's not its purpose at all. The simulator is not intended to work, but to appear to the pilot somehow like the actual thing for purposes other than its normal ones, e.g. to allow ground training (including in unusual situations like all-engine failure). So simulator definition would be: something that can appear to human, to some extend, like the original, but cannot replace it for actual use. In addition the pilot will know that the simulator is a simulator.

I don't think we'll see any ROM simulator, because ROM are not interacting with human beings, nor we'll see any plane emulator, because planes cannot have a replacement performing the same functions in the real world.

In my view the model inside an emulator or a simulator can be anything, and has not to be similar to the model of the original. A ROM emulator model will likely be software instead of hardware, MS Flight Simulator cannot be more software than it is.

This comparison of both terms will contradict the currently selected answer (from Toybuilder) which puts the difference on the internal model, while my suggestion is that the difference is whether the fake can or cannot be used to perform the actual function in the actual world (to some accepted extend, indeed).

Note that the plane simulator will have also to simulate the earth, the sun, the wind, etc, which are not part of the plane, so a plane simulator will have to mimic some aspects of the plane, as well as the environment of the plane because it is not used in this actual environment, but in a training room.

This is a big difference with the emulator which emulates only the orginal, and its purpose is to be used in the environment of the original with no need to emulate it. Back to the plane context... what could be a plane emulator? Maybe a train that will connect two airports -- actually two plane steps -- carrying passengers, with stewardesses onboard, with car interior looking like an actual plane cabin, and with captain saying "ladies and gentlemen our altitude is currenlty 10 kms and the temperature at our destination is 24°C". Its benefit is difficult to see, hum...

As a conclusion, the emulator is a real thing intended to work, the simulator is a fake intended to trick the user.

Comment: The phrase "ROM emulator" reminds me of virtual video game consoles.

Comment: Can a washing machine be called as a wash emulator? Or an ATM as a bank withdrawal desk emulator?

Comment: @lousycoder: In this context emulator is somehow close (as opposed to simulator), but I'd rather talk about automation for two reasons: 1/ the user sees clearly the difference with the original, 2/ the device replaces a human and automation is exactly that.

Answer (score 14):

To understand the difference between a simulator and an emulator, keep in mind that a simulator tries to mimic the behavior of a real device. For example, in the case of the iOS Simulator, it simulates the real behavior of an actual iPhone/iPad device. However, the Simulator itself uses the various libraries installed on the Mac (such as QuickTime) to perform its rendering so that the effect looks the same as an actual iPhone. In addition, applications tested on the Simulator are compiled into x86 code, which is the byte-code understood by the Simulator. A real iPhone device, conversely, uses ARM-based code.

In contrast, an emulator emulates the working of a real device. Applications tested on an emulator are compiled into the actual byte-code used by the real device. The emulator executes the application by translating the byte-code into a form that can be executed by the host computer running the emulator.

To understand the subtle difference between simulation and emulation, imagine you are trying to convince a child that playing with knives is dangerous. To simulate this, you pretend to cut yourself with a knife and groan in pain. To emulate this, you actually cut yourself.

Comment: Don't try this at home kids :D

Answer (score 10):

In more or less normal parlance: If your software can do everything the mimicked system can do, it's an emulator. If it only approximates the results of a system (IT or otherwise), it's a simulator.

Answer (score 9):

An emulator is a model of a system which will accept any valid input that that the emulated system would accept, and produce the same output or result. So your software is an emulator, only if it reproduces the *behavior* of the emulated system precisely.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a very precise definition of Emulation. So, for example Wine is a simulator because it doesn't necessarily give the same *precise* output defined in Windows?

Comment: Be careful about trying to shoehorn WINE into an either/or of emulator or simulator.  WINE is a compatibility layer, which makes binaries from one system run on the binary API layer of another system.  You might call it an adaptor.  I suppose simulator isn't a bad way to understand it either, but it's not really much closer than emulator.

Comment: WINE is emulation, in this spectrum.  It has the outside appearance of linking Windows binaries but if you were to look to the internals you wouldn't learn anything about Windows.

Answer (score 9):

Some years ago I came up with a very short adage that, I believe, captures the essence of the difference quite nicely:

> A simulator is an emulator on a mission.

By that I mean that you use an emulator when you can't use the real thing, and you use a simulator when you can't use the real thing *and you want to find something out about it*.

Answer (score 8):

Simple Explanation.

If you want to convert your PC (running Windows) into Mac, you can do either of these:

> (1) You can simply install a Mac theme on your Windows. So, your PC feels more like Mac, but you can't actually run any Mac programs. `(SIMULATION)`

(or)

> (2) You can program your PC to run like Mac (I'm not sure if this is possible :P ). Now you can even run Mac programs successfully and expect the same output as on Mac. `(EMULATION)`

In the first case, you can experience Mac, but you can't expect the same output as on Mac. 
In the second case, you can expect the same output as on Mac, but still the fact remains that it is only a PC.

Comment: This is both simple and completely wrong.  (2) is close to emulation, but (1) is neither emulation nor simulation.

Answer (score 5):

**Simulator:** it is similar to interpreter.
i.e. it actually executes the real code in **line by line** to mimic the behaviour

**Emulator:** it is similar executable.
i.e. it takes compiled code and executes it.

Answer (score 4):

The distintion between the two terms is a bit fuzzy.  Coming from a world where "Emulators" are pieces of hardware that allow you debug embedded systems.  And remember products that allowed you to have ICE (In Circuit Emulation) capabilities to debug a PC platform, I find the use of the term "Emulation" to be a somewhat of a misnomer for software that SIMULATES the behaviour of a piece of hardware.

My justification for the current use of the term is Emulation is that it may "augment" the functionality, and only is concerned with a "reasonable" approximation of the behaviour of the system.

ICE: (In Circuit Emulation)
A piece of hardware that is plugged into a board in place of the actual processor.  It allows you to run the system as if the actual processor was present.  Typically these have a variant of the processor on them to actually execute the software with glue logic to allow the user to break executation and single step under hardware control.  Some would also provide logging capability.  Most modern processors development systems have replace ICE type emulation with JTAG Emulation, where the JTAG just talks to the processor via a special purpose serial link and all execution is perform by the processor mounted on the board.

Software EMULATOR:
An 0x86 emulator is only concerned with being able to execute 0x86 assembly language, not providing accurate cycle per cycle behaviourial model of a SPECIFIC 0x86 processor.  Bochs is an example of this.  QEMU does this, but also allows "virtualization" using special kernel modules.

SIMULATOR:
Texas Instruments provides a CYCLE ACCURATE behaviourial model of there processors for software development that is intended to be a accurate SIMULATION of SPECIFIC processor cores behavior for the developers to use prior to having working hardware.

Software EMULATOR augmenting functionality:
BLEEM not only allowed you to run Playstation Software, but also allowed the display to be output with higher resolution than the Playstation was able to provide, and also took advantage of more advanced capabilities of GPUs that were avaliable.  (i.e. Better blending and smoothing of textures.)

Answer (score 4):

An emulator is an alternative to the real system but a simulator is used to optimize, understand and estimate the real system.

Answer (score 4):

A simulation is a system that behaves **similar** to something else, but is implemented in an entirely different way. It provides the basic behavior of a system but may not necessarily abide by all of the rules of the system being simulated. It is there to give you an idea about how something works.

An emulation is a system that behaves **exactly** like something else, and abides by all of the rules of the system being emulated. It is effectively a complete replication of another system, right down to being binary compatible with the emulated system's inputs and outputs, but operating in a different environment to the environment of the original emulated system. The rules are fixed, and cannot be changed or the system fails.

Answer (score 4):

Both terms are something completely different and only intersect very little.  To find the right term is actually very easy, just think about following:

**A simulation does not do anything for real.**  You can study it, for example how computer work, but it usually has no outcome other than that.    A plane crash in a Flight Simulator causes no real harm.  A weather forecast simulation itself does not change the weather.

**An emulation does something for real.**  You can work with an emulated computer like with a physical one and create documents with it.  And a plane crash in a Flight Emulator would have an outcome, like people experiencing the real impact including possible physical harm.

Your confusion probably stems from the fact, that "studying the simulation" and "accessing the emulation" often is quite the same thing.

You are not alone with your confusion.  The Film "Matrix" speaks of a simulation.  However The Matrix is running an emulation, as it has real impact on all members of The Matrix.  In contrast the training room has no real impact, so this is a simulation (of The Matrix).

Let's see some examples.

## Simulated vs. Emulated Rain

Take a water hose in the garden and let it rain.  What's the difference between simulation and emulation here?

When you are simulating rain, people still will blame you for getting wet.  Your rain has some real impact on the world, but your simulation hasn't, as the simulation does not fool anybody in that it is real rain.

In contrast, when you are emulating rain, people would blame the weather.  This is, your emulated rain really behaves like rain in reality.
This rain emulation hence distorts reality,
in making people belie in the wrong culprit.

> It took me quite some time to understand that.
> Hence it isn't easy nor obvious which explains all the confusion.

Keep in mind that a simulation can have sideeffects,
like the weather forecast is based on simulations,
which takes quite some computing power and thus electrical energy,
which has an environmental impact.

Hence in the example of "simulated rain", people getting wet just is a sideffect and not part of the simulation.  Same is true if you simulate a rainbow with this simulated rain.  While the property of "how rainbows work" is part of this simulation, the simulation itself is not providing the rainbow, this just happens due to refraction of the sun on the sideffect of the waterdrops.

## Simulated vs. Emulated Computer

While you might think "a simulated computer can have an outcome" this is practically wrong reasoning.  If you save files onto a simulated harddrive, these files cannot leave the simulated drive outside of the simulation.  You can obtain the files by studying the simulated drive, but this is not part of the simulation itself.

In case the harddrive saves the data such, that the data is actually usable outside of the simulation, you have an emulated harddrive within the simulation to do so.

So an emulation can be part of a simulation and vice versa.

## Simulated vs. Emulated Filesystem

If you simulate a filesystem, you probably, for practicability, will choose to save the files onto your real filesystem as-is (perhaps with some additional meta-information).  In that case the simulation seems to create real "value" outside of the simulation:  Usable files!

But this is just by coincidence, because your simulated filesystem actually emulates a filesystem as well.  You actually emulated the outside filesystem inside your simulation!

## Simulated vs. Emulated TPM or HSM

A good example of the difference is, when you think of security.  [A TPM is a specific device to keep it's own keys secure (source of identity) while an HSM is a general device to secure foreign keys (verify identity)](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/244636/41742).

> Fun Fact:  My fingers constantly type TMP instead of TPM.

If you simulate a TPM this has a huge effect on security, because then you can observe the internal states of the TPM.  Which renders all the security void.  Even that such a simulation can give you valuable hints of improving the design of a TPM itself, you won't want to expose precious data to the simulated TPM for real.

However if you emulate a TPM you will try to hide these internal states to the outside as good as you can.  Such an emulated TPM then can be possibly used to really secure something else better than without it.

With a real TPM you cannot emulate the properties of a real HSM.  All you can archive is to simulate an HSM, but this will not have the security properties of a real HSM, so all data which is stored in this simulated HSM will not be protected (they will only be protected within the simulation itself).

In contrast, with a real HSM you can emulate a TPM with all properties of a real TPM.  For this the HSM needs to be constructed such, that no information needs to leave the HSM which does not leave a TPM as well.

(Please note that I do not know anything about HSMs or TPMs in particular, so it might be that there are no HSMs out there which are able to provide emulated TPMs.)

## Simulated vs. Emulated World

If our world is simulated, we are simulations, too.  Hence some spectator (let's call her God) can look at us and change the simulation any time.  Also we cannot find out if we are simulated or not.  As I am pretty sure that I know that I am, I do not think I am simulated, because self-awareness looks like an effect with a real component to me, which contradicts simulation.  This also means, our world cannot be a simulation, too, as a simulation can only affect me like the world does, if I am part of the simulation.

But our world still can be emulated (like in the Film "Matrix"), as all I have to "prove the world" is my state of mind and sensory input, which I cannot verify, as I cannot leave myself.  If I am not part of the emulation, then there should be a chance to observe discontinuity (like in the film "Matrix"), in case the emulation does not work flawlessly.

This changes when I emulated, too, like running an OS in an emulator.  Then I cannot observe such errors, as my state can be reset from within the emulation (call it: Sleep) without observable discontinuation.

However I rather think that the world is a holographic hallucination than something like an emulation.  Because if it is emulated, then I am pwned by somebody (call him Rick) who is running the emulation for some purpose, while a hallucination is purely my own thing.

I stop here, because hallucinations lead us to something completely different.

Comment: How does self awareness contradict a simulation, you're the result of particles developing in to a life form

Comment: @spO_oks The only thing I can be really sure to be true is, that I am real.  Because I am.  Everything else can be just a hallucination.  (I.E. I cannot prove that you are real nor that there is anything else than me.  It is only common sense that there must be something like a world outside of me which is not me, as this is the most reasonable assumption, as the opposite assumption, that there is nothing else than me, makes things a bit futile.)  As simulation, per definition, cannot change anything for real, but I change, hence life being a simulation contradicts the fact, that I am.

Answer (score 3):

This question is probably best answered by taking a look at historical practice.

In the past, I've seen gaming console emulators on PC for the PlayStation & SEGA.

Simulators are commonplace when referring to software that tries to mimic real life actions, such as driving or flying. Gran Turismo and Microsoft Flight Simulator spring to mind as classic examples of simulators.

As for the linguistic difference, emulation usually refers to the action of copying someone's (or something's) praiseworthy characteristics or behaviors. Emulation is distinct from imitation, in which a person is copied for the purpose of mockery.

The linguistic meaning of the verb 'simulation' is essentially to pretend or mimic someone or something.

Answer (score 3):

In computer science both a simulation and emulation produce the same outputs, from the same inputs, that the original system does; However, an emulation also uses the **same processes** to achieve it and is made out of the **same materials**. A simulation uses different processes from the original system.  Also worth noting is the term replication, which is the intermediate of the two - using the same processes but being made out of a different material.

So if I want to run my old Super Mario Bros game on my PC I use an SNES *emulator*, because it is using the same or similar computer code (processes) to run the game, and uses the same or similar materials (silicon chip).
However, if I want to fly a Boeing 747 jet on my PC I use a flight *simulator* because it uses completely different processes from the original (there are no actual wings, lift or aerodynamics involved!).

Here are the exact definitions taken from a computer science glossary:

A simulation is a model of a system that captures the functional connections between inputs and outputs of the system, but without necessarily being based on processes that are the same as, or similar to, those of the system itself.

A replication is a model of a system that captures the functional connections between inputs and outputs of the system and is based on processes that are the same as, or similar to, those of the system itself.

An emulation is a model of some system that captures the functional connections between inputs and outputs of the system, based on processes that are the same as, or similar to, those of that system, and that is built of the same materials as that system.

Reference: The Open University, M366 Glossary 1.1, 2007

Answer (score 3):

Both are models of an object that you have some means of controlling inputs to and observing outputs from.

The key difference is that:

- With an ***emulator***, you want the output *exactly match* what the object you are emulating would produce.
- With a ***simulator***, you want certain properties of your output to be *similar to* what the object would produce.

Let me give an example -- suppose you want to do some system testing to see how adding a new sensor (like a thermometer) to a system would affect the system. You know that the thermometer sends a message 8 time a second containing its measurement.

Simulation -- if you do not have the thermometer yet, but you want to test that this message rate will not overload you system, you can simulate the sensor by attaching a unit that sends a random number 8 times a second. You can run any test that does not rely on the actual value the sensor sends.

Emulation -- suppose you have a very expensive thermometer that measures to 0.001 C, and you want to see if you can get by with a cheaper thermometer that only measures to the nearest 0.5 C. You can emulate the cheaper thermometer using an expensive thermometer and then rounding the reading to the nearest 0.5 C and running tests that rely on the temperature values.

Note that simulations can also be used for forecasting or predicting behavior. Finite element analysis simulations are used in many applications, including weather prediction and virtual wind tunnels.

The definitions of the terms:

- emulation -- surpass or exactly match
- simulate -- imitate in appearance or character

Comment: Note -- this is very similar to the answer to a question that has been marked as a dup of this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174638/whats-the-difference-between-emulation-and-simulation). I did add a definition of the terms (asked for in the question but not yet answered) and also added some info about uses for simulation (finite element analysis) for something more than mimicking a device.

Answer (score 3):

The definitions of the words describe the difference the best. A google search gives the following definitions of simulate and emulate:

**simulate** *imitate the appearance or character of.*

**emulate** *match or surpass (a person or achievement), typically by imitation.*

A simulation imitates a system. An emulation simulates a system so well that it could replace it or may even surpass it.

In computing, an emulation would be a drop in replacement for the system it is emulating. Often times it will even outperform the system it is imitating. For example, game console emulators usually make improvements such as greater hardware compatibility, better performance, and improved audio/video quality.

Simulations, on the other hand, are limited by them being models. They are a best attempt to mimic a system, but not replacements for it. There are hardware emulators because hardware can be imitated and it would be hard to tell the difference. There is no Farming Emulator because there is no emulation that could replace actual farming. We can only simulate a model of farming to gain insight on how to farm better.

Answer (score 2):

A Virtual PC tries to **emulate** a Computer, *from the point of view of a Programmer* BUT, at the same time, it **simulates** a Computer *from the point of view of a Electrical Engineer*.

Answer (score 1):

*Simulator* is something more broader than *Emulator* and it seems like the duality of this terms is overthought in the posts above.

**Emulator**

People decided to use a new word *emulation* in the "computer world" when they started replacing some hardware parts of the existing system in straightforward manner - imitating their behaviour and relying on the computational nature to be sure to not break something and leave everything in the equivalent state. *So we have emulated the piece of this! (and the whole still works as before)*

Emulator usually used in narrow sense in digital area as replacement and virtualization - presenting in digital form as a piece of software - of something known and existed before (virtual chips, circuit boards, electronic devices). So when the world became more digital and brought the *emulator* word to the masses,  the masses added uncertainty to it (or additional reasons).

**Simulator**

First of all, I saw many comments about emulators do or replace something real but simulators not.

BUT flight simulator is used for a real thing - it trains pilots, gives them skill up and knowledge and it replaces expensive real planes and saves much of money. And we cannot just say a plane-emulator because we have inner feeling that this is much more than that, so we call it *simulator* :) Plane simulator could contain emulated radar or transponder that is true.

Contra-statements that simulators are used for analysis and study (and emulators for something real), but that *analysis and study* not less a real thing than emulated GSM boards (even more in the informational age we live in). Analysis adds a value to the business, cuts costs or points out to profits not less than the replaced (emulated) hardware.

Simulator is similar to modelling of something that we can't obtain for some reason (cost, technology, physical impossibility). It is usually simulated for something new or intangible or complex or not properly known to us like market, weather, combustion, user. So here comes the flight, black hole, stock exchange, simulations.

**So finally:**

1. Simulator is broader than Emulator
2. Simulator tends to imitate/model more global processes/things in general with ability to narrow the imitation down (e.g. capacitor simulator with presets representing some known models)
3. Emulator tends to imitate certain hardware devices with certain specification, known characteristics and properties (e.g. SNES emulator, Intel 8087 or Roland TB-303)

**As for words origin**

All came from Latin and mean:

- *emulate* is "to be equal" (looks like more aggressive and straightforward - rivalry)
- *simulate* is "to be similar" (looks like more sly and tricky - imitation)

Answer (score 1):

**Emulation** is like
*Abstruction.
It shows **what** it can do.
Example: Car driving emulation.*

**Simulation** is like
*Encaptulation.
It shows **how** it can do
Example: Car engine inner activity.*

Answer (score 0):

Emulator:

Consider a situation that you know only English and you are in China. In order to interact with a Chinese person you need a translator. Now, role of translator is that it will seek input from you in English and convert to Chinese and and give that input to the Chinese person and gets response from the Chinese person and convert to English and give the output to you in English. Now that translator and Chinese person is the emulator. Both combine will provide similar functionality as if you were communicating with the English person. So hardware may be different but functionality will be same.

Simulator:

I can't give better example than SPICE or flight simulator. Both will replace hardware component behavior with the software or mathematical model which will behave similar to the hardware.

In the end it depends on the context that which solution better suits project needs.

Answer (score -3):

The simulator is necessarily a scale model.
Emulators pretend to be a 1:1 model.

Comment: This doesn't tends to differentiate between a simulator and an emulator. Please edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).