# What's the difference between emulation and simulation?

Tags: emulation, simulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simulator or Emulator? What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584617/simulator-or-emulator-what-is-the-difference)

In simple understandable terms, what is the difference between the two terms?

[I have already looked at [this](http://www.hpmuseum.org/cgi-sys/cgiwrap/hpmuseum/archv015.cgi?read=71816), [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_simulation) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator)]

Answer (score 333, accepted):

(Using as an example your first link)

You want to duplicate the behavior of an old HP calculator, there are two options:

1. You write new program that draws the calculator's display and keys, and when the user clicks on the keys, your programs does what the old calculator did. This is a *Simulator*
2. You get a dump of the calculator's firmware, then write a program that loads the firmware and interprets it the same way the microprocessor in the calculator did. This is an *Emulator*

The *Simulator* tries to duplicate the *behavior* of the device.
The *Emulator* tries to duplicate the *inner workings* of the device.

Comment: I've never seen a simpler explanation... Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yes -- that's an excellent way of summarizing that. Thanks!

Comment: More specifically, an emulator attempts to duplicate the entire behavior of a device from an external viewpoint. It may or may not need to duplicate the inner workings of a device to accomplish that. A simulation attempts to duplicate a specific subset of a device's behavior.

Comment: I disagree with the answer given here. Both examples are simulation, just at different levels. If you unplug the processor from the calculator, plug in a probe, run the calculator, and you get the same answers, that probe is an emulator. Better answers are given below by Jay Elston, coxy, and semiuseless.

Comment: Funny, this answer says the exact opposite thing to the answer given to the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1584617/485561).

Comment: Great answer, but IMO, it would be correctly to change `device` noun to `system`, because in addition to devices such things like process, some behavior directly, etc. could be implemented too.

Comment: There seems to be a difference in opinion to what the words mean in the context of technology, as demonstrated by the diametrically opposed but popular [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1584701/1257965) to a duplicate question. I'll side with Carlos' answer because in my mind there's a distinction to on what level something is imitated and I think that distinction is made correctly in his answer. See also Peter Hans van den Muijzenberg's take on [this page](http://ed-thelen.org/comp-hist/emulation.html) about stomach-ache and eating unripe apples.

Comment: Does that mean that a flight simulator is actually a flight emulator?

Comment: So that's the difference between Xcode Simulator and Android Studio Emulator :)

Comment: Woah! This answer contradicts the accepted answer on its [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584617/simulator-or-emulator-what-is-the-difference). The duplicate answer doesn't 'emulate' *(read duplicate)* the original answer! :P

Comment: This is opposite to my understanding of the two different terms. As an example, I believe that a digital piano *emulates* an analogue piano (realtime, same external observable behavior), while you can *simulate* the collision of two galaxies in software (not realtime, and you only wish to inspect certain internal physics of the collision, not how the complete system would behave - e.g. exactly how it would look on the sky).

Answer (score 14):

This is a hard question to answer definitively because the terms and often misused or confused.

Often, an emulator is a complete re-implementation of a particular device or platform. The emulator acts exactly like the real device would. For example, a NES emulator implements the CPU, the sound chip, the video output, the controller signals, etc. The unmodified code from a NES castridge can be dumped and then the resulting image can be loaded into our emulator and played.

A simulator is a partial implementation of a device/platform, it does just enough for its own purposes. For example, the iPhone Simulator runs an "iPhone app" that has been specifically compiled to target x86 and the Cocoa API rather than the real device's ARM CPU and Cocoa Touch API. However, the binary that we run in the simulator would not work on the real device.

Comment: An NES emulator is not a complete re-implementation, it merely *appears* to act like an NES to an outside observer.  This is of course what you want, as the user of the emulator, but it does not implicate the internal implementation which is likely very different from the original device you are emulating.

Answer (score 7):

Both are models of an object that you have some means of controlling inputs and observing outputs. With an emulator, you want the output to be exactly what the object you are emulating would produce. With a simulator, you want certain properties of your output to be similar to what the object would produce.

Let me give an example -- suppose you want to do some system testing to see how adding a new sensor (like a thermometer) to a system would affect the system. You know that the thermometer sends a message 8 time a second containing its measurement.

Simulation -- if you do not have the thermometer yet, but you want to test that this message rate will not overload you system, you can simulate the sensor by attaching a unit that sends a random number 8 times a second. You can run any test that does not rely on the actual value the sensor sends.

Emulation -- suppose you have a very expensive thermometer that measures to 0.001 C, and you want to see if you can get by with a cheaper thermometer that only measures to the nearest 0.5 C. You can emulate the cheaper thermometer using an expensive thermometer by rounding the reading to the nearest 0.5 C and running tests that rely on the temperature values.

Comment: Check the links, he's talking about hardware emulation

Answer (score 4):

I do not know whether this is the general opinion, but I've always differentiated the two by what they are used for. An emulator is used if you actually want to use the emulated machine for its output. A simulator, on the other hand, is for when you want to study the simulated machine or test its behaviour.

For example, if you want to write some state machine logic in your application (which is running on a general purpose CPU), you write a small state machine emulator. If you want to study the efficiency or viability of a state machine for a particular problem, you write a simulator.

Comment: That's pretty much my understanding, too. I even coined a catch-phrase for that distinction: "A simulator is an emulator on a mission".

Answer (score 3):

Based on software and system engineering experience, I'd summarise the difference as follows:

Simulation: for me, this is always in software - every aspect of the real system is only MODELLED by some code and/or mathematics. Simulation attempts to accurately reproduce the behaviour (or predict it) of the real system, but only approximates it.

Emulation: As opposed to simulation, it does not APPROXIMATE the behaviour of the real system, it COPIES the behaviour of the real system. An emulator may involve hardware. But it may also be entirely in software. E.g. you get these software EMULATORS for old game consoles like the Sega Genesis. That is an emulator because it COPIES the real genesis functionality so much so that you can run the original Genesis code in the emulator. A genesis simulator would not be able to run the original code, it would only APPROXIMATE its behaviour, producing similar results, depending on how good the models of the original system were.

An emulator of a system component can be included in a larger system, completely replacing the component it is emulating - a simulator could not because it is not an accurate enough representation of the original component behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

An *"emulator"* is a term for a software-based hardware-simulator, but in general the two are synonyms.

Comment: I don't really know anything, but I would guess that sometimes a simulator may not actually emulate the actual low level hardware, but instead be a peice of software that simulates the high level platform apis.

Comment: There is a distinction between the two.  "Emulation" implies a more detailed duplication of behaviors than does "simulation".

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the hardware development world. . .

Simulation tests functionality.  2+2 = 4 etc

Emulation tests the functionality on the specific environment (64-bit, 16-bit, fingers and toes).

Here is a food example:

You have two pieces of bread, one knife, peanut butter and jelly and will be giving them to a kindergartner.
You write instructions on how to make a sandwich.

In simulation, you would act out the process, pretend you opened the jars, pretend spreading the peanut butter etc.

If at the end of the instructions your are left with only jelly and not peanut butter then you failed the simulation and you need to fix your instructions.  On the other hand if you have a complete "sandwich" then the instructions should be valid

In emulation, you would use close representations of the actual parts (same bread, knife peanut butter etc).  What happens if you gave your kindergartner a cheap plastic knife and really really thick peanut butter??  The knife would break in emulation and the instructions would need to be clarified or fixed to accommodate this problem.  In this case you might suggest warming up the peanut butter in the microwave.

In practice:  Consider a 64-bit system that you are programming in and a 32bit system that will actually be running the code.  You add two very very large numbers and print the result.  In simulation everything works (you managed to get the code right to add two numbers)  In emulation however you find that you get the wrong answer.  What happened?  The emulation of the 32-bit system was unable to handle the large numbers.  This is an example of correct functionality (i.e. simulation) but not proper support for your runtime environment (emulation)

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive me if I'm wrong.  And I have to admit upfront that I haven't done any research on these 2 terms.  Anyway...

Emulation is to mimic something with detailed known results, whatever the internal behaviors actually are.  We only try to get things done and don't care much about what goes on inside.

Simulation, on the other hand, is to mimic something with some known behaviors to study something not being known yet.

my 2cents

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example - we recently developed a simulation model to measure the remote transmission response time of a yet-to-be-developed system.  An emulation analysis would not have given us the answer in time to upgrade the bandwidth capacity so simulation was our approach.  Because we were mostly interested in determining bandwidth needs, we cared primarily about transaction size and volume, not the processing of the system.  The simulation model was on a stand-alone piece of software that was designed to model discrete-event processes.  To summarize in response to your question, emulation is a type of simulation.  But, in this case, simulation was NOT an emulation because it didn't fully represent the new system, only the size and volume of transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused between the two processes. I found this simple explaination about the difference between Emulators and Simulators

1. Simulator:
   Suppose you have written assembly program in a file and corresponding exe
   file is ready. The simulator is the pc software which reads the instructions
   from the exe and 'minmics' the operation of the processor.
2. Emulator:
   Emulator is a (PC software + a processor). The Processor can be plugged into
   the TARGET BOARD when you want to test the developed software in real time
   to check run time bugs. When not in use it can be unplugged. The Processor
   will have a parallel or JTAG interface with the PC for downloading the exe
   file for execution.

Hence, whereas the Simulator is slow in execution, Emulator will be able to
give real time verification of the developed code.
Generally you will test your developed code on simulator first and then go
for checking on emulator.

source : http://www.dsprelated.com/groups/c6x/show/148.php