# wan simulator for windows

Tags: simulator, wan

Is there an open source /freeware wan similator for windows ?

Comment: What is a WAN simulator? What does it do?

Comment: It is a tool that can simlate a WAN, create network errors- basically to test how your application handles the network errors which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Example reference; for the [now old] Win server 2003, MS advised using one;  Measuring Load Time for a Web Page ;; https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778898(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Also, be aware of the [difference between simulation and emulation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1584646/3041008). I guess that OP asks for an emulator, which emulates network conditions typically found in Wide Area Networks for real sockets, instead of simulating them in an abstract model for analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For windows, there is [eexnetlab](http://www.eex-dev.net/index.php?id=38&L=1) (Website German, Program English). It's a program to simulate networks.

You can use it to create a virtual bridge between two network interfaces and place two wan emulators between them (one for every direction).

Comment: Looks like this will server my purpose. I cant open the link above (.. wanemulator.png). Also I could not find the english documentaiton. Thanks,

Comment: The website is available now on English too. :).
The documentation is installed with the software, how-to's are also available on english on the website.

Answer (score 2):

http://wanem.sourceforge.net/

Comment: 2014-02 their beta v3 was released. For the older version one person had a kernel panic a while ago,  .WANem - Wide Area Network Emulator / Bugs / #21 Kernel panic ;; http://sourceforge.net/p/wanem/bugs/21/

Answer (score 0):

Haven't personally tried, but [Clumsy](http://jagt.github.io/clumsy/) seems easy to use. It might not have all of the features of some *heavier* solutions though:

> clumsy will choose which packets to capture by given filter, in which in can specify whether it's inbound or outbound, tcp or udp, socket port or ip, or a logical combination of many of those criterias.
>   ...
>   After packets are captured, you can choose to enable provided functions to worsen perspective network condition:
>   * Lag, hold the packets for a short period of time to emulate network lagging.
>   * Drop, randomly discard packets.
>   * Throttle, block traffic for a given time frame, then send them in a single batch.
>   * Duplicate, send cloned packets right after to the original one.
>   * Out of order, re-arrange the order of packets.
>   * Tamper, nudge bits of packet's content.