# iPhone simulator for 3G devices

Tags: iphone, ios, simulator

I recently released an iPhone app.
Of course I testes this app in simulator and on my 3GS device.

One day after the release, I got two bad customer reviews, telling that the app would crash the whole time.

That's extremly bad since I want to provide a bugfree app. My problem is now to find the problem. I can't find a crash report in the iTunes connect and it looks like everything is finde on 3GS ans simulator.

My idea is, that the memory on 3G devices may be too small and cause a crash. But how to test this out.
Can the simulator be configured to start with the 3G configuration (including less memory) ?

What else can I do ? I can't find any memory leaks or other stuff that could have caused the troubled.

Comment: I have a 3G, so I can help you to test this.:)

Answer (score 4):

iPhone Simulator is a software simulator, not a hardware emulator, so it cannot be configured to replicate the hardware constraints found on actual devices. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544588/difference-between-iphone-simulator-and-android-emulator/4544605#4544605).

You need to test on an iPhone 3G device.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a blog post](http://wjlafrance.net/?p=188) about an issue like this a few weeks ago. You need an iPhone 3G. The unstated and unwritten rule of iOS target selection is "if you didn't test it on one, you don't support it, so don't pretend to." iPhone 3G's are dropping price, so you can get one on eBay / Craigslist at a reasonable price.