# Workflow Efficiency: Testing Front End on Mobile Devices

Tags: css, iphone, mobile

Recently I became comfortable with "desktop" development.  Meaning -- I work on localhost and develop the front end, readjusting the browser size to see how the responsiveness is working out.

To test this it was simple.  Refresh the page, and see what's changed.

But enter iPhone, iPad and (oh man,) Android resolutions.  I find my workflow extremely inefficient to test how my media queries are being interpreted.

As of now, I commit changes, push to Heroku, assets are precompiled etc. etc. I grab my phone.  Load up the page, hit refresh, server is restarting, 30 seconds later my page loads.

My code either fixed a problem, or it didn't.  So it's back to square one or I'm  on to the next thing.

Question being:
**What is the most efficient way to test each little css adjustment for mobile sites? My method cannot be remotely close to efficient.**

(If this question is more appropriate for meta-so I can repost there... I'm half expecting downvotes, but I feel this is a pertinent question every noobie front-end dev will come across at some point)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would using Chrome's nifty emulator: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/mobile-emulation .

Also, see this post for more: [test mobile website in desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427736/test-mobile-website-in-desktop-browser)

Comment: The chrome answer is the one I was looking for.  This is amazing, although it's not exactly matching my iPhone's interpretation when I selected device: iphone5... I think I need to play around a bit.