# is there anyway i can check the use of meta name="viewport" on my laptop browser

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If anyone can help me understand the use of --

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Just trying to check usage of this line, by removing this line from Web Page( written in Bootstrap) & then re-sizing  my Laptop browser window. Then tried to  changing the initial scale to 0.5,2,3,4  & width parameters to 500, 1500 etc. but no changes appear on my webpage. Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [test mobile website in desktop browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12427736/test-mobile-website-in-desktop-browser)

Answer (score 0):

They are viewport meta tags, and is most applicable on mobile browsers.

**width=device-width**

This means, we are telling to the browser “my website adapts to your device width”.

**initial-scale**

This defines the scale of the website, This parameter sets the initial zoom level, which means 1 CSS pixel is equal to 1 viewport pixel. This parameter help when you're changing orientation, or preventing default zooming. Without this parameter, responsive site won't work.

**How to see the Impact:**

If you just want to see the impact on your browser, just open a webpage like [www.example.com](http://example.com/) , open the page in chrome and open developer tool/ inspect web page.

Select the device mode to mobile and change the value of initial-scale from 1 to 2 or any value, that will show you impact of initial-scale.

Comment: Awesome, its working in Mobile mode. But if it doesn't applies to Desktop & Browser Windows ? Why no effects on Desktop & Laptop Browser screen when changing initial scale & device-width.

Comment: meta name="viewport" layout type is specifically designed for mobile/handheld device and came in existence only to load desktop page on mobile device. And if you want to go more into depth, please look into below links. All the description talks only about mobile device.

[link](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-device-adapt-1/) and [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

Note: If you like the answer, please give a thumbs up.

Comment: @Ishaan is the things clear? did you looked on the link shared for your reference.