# Why Android Emulator (AVD) is so slow?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm having a hard time developing android applications. My AVD takes ages to boot up, besides it lacks of performance. Touches have a delay or lag and it doesn't look as professional as the Xcode simulator. Is there something I can do?

I am getting this error when running my app:

- The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
- You must restart adb and Eclipse.
- Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/Users/******/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's an Emulator. Not a Simulator.

Answer (score 2):

I use a .bat file:

```
@echo off
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

that helps me when adb is not responding. You need to add the adb.exe path to environment variable, so it can be executed from any location.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any seamsless way to use it without command-line codes? I'm looking for a stable IDE, just like Xcode if possible

Comment: After over 2 years of Android development with Eclipse, I'm still using the bat file when adb doe not respond. So, if this solution works for your put a link on your taskbar to restart Adb.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do the same then. I hope Google gives developers a better way to develop, the current tools do not seem seamless.

Comment: @Xenia: In DDMS, in the Devices view, there's a "Reset ADB" option (click the drop-arrow in the toolbar) that does the equivalent of this batch file.

Comment: Do I have to do it everytime I compile? Is there any more professional solution/IDE for Android development?

Comment: Not every time, just if you see something wrong with ADB. I usually use hardware devices to debug my app, and then, in a final step, the emulator to check the UI for different screen sizes/resolutions. Problems for me arises only there.

Comment: @Seraphim I see you are a DCD follower. Love them myself.

Comment: @Namphibian Yes! a little OT but... viva DCD! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are welcome to use [the x86 emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm), which should address the "ages to boot up" and "lacks of performance" issues, at minimum.

The rest of your problems feels like more of an issue with the overall development environment (e.g., too little available RAM on the development machine), though it is possible the x86 emulator will help there too.

Comment: I'm using a macbook with 8GB ram and 512GB Flash Storage. Maybe not enough memory. I'll try the x86 then. Thanks.

Comment: @Xenia: It's not only the installed RAM, but how much is available, taking into account anything else you normally have running.

Comment: I'm new to Android development. I thought it was as smooth as developing for iOS, where I don't have to worry about emulator RAM, memory, etc. thanks anyway, I appreciate your help.

Comment: The iphone simulator works a bit like the x86 one, it does not emulate an arm, even though current iDevices, like most android devices, are arm-based.  Emulating the arm chip, its memory access, and graphics is what makes the traditional android emulator slow.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using the [x86 Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-vm) you can also use [Emulator Snapshots](http://tools.android.com/recent/emulatorsnapshots) to improve boot time.  With snapshots even the arm emulator boots in a few seconds.

Here is a good post about [Emulation vs Simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544588/difference-between-iphone-simulator-and-android-emulator). Basically the emulator provides a more realistic test environment.

Comment: I'm using snapshots and GPU already, but still seems years behind the quality of Xcode's emulator.

Comment: There are trade-offs to both approaches and one of them is speed. However, when you run an app on the emulator you can be reasonably confident it will run on devices.