# Steps required to check app on simulator in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I just started development in IOS I want to check app on simulator (app which is app store ).
How to check this app on IOS simulator ?

Secondly If I am in window is it possible to check app which is app store ? mean is there any online simulator available on net ?

Comment: Step 0: spell the name of the operating system correctly (iOS is not IOS). Step 1: click the "build and run" button in Xcode.

Comment: Is it just me or is this very confusing on what is being asked?  "is it possible to check app which is app store"?

Comment: Please clarify the phrase "app which is app store." You've used it twice, and frankly it doesn't make sense. Is this an app that you hope to submit to the app store? Are you talking about an app that you've downloaded from the app store? An app from the app store is by definition built for an iOS device and cannot run on the simulator; you have to build specifically for the simulator if you want to run the app there.

Comment: @Walls, i think you are right and he wants to know how to run an app from the app store on the simulator, which is of course not possible

Comment: sorry all https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pontefy/id660611525?mt=8#

Comment: I want to check this app on simulator

Comment: I don't have source code and device ..Only simulator available .Actually I am blackberry developer in which .cod file will run on simulator

Comment: why guys you give me negative band ..!!

Comment: I am just asking some basic question ? is it true ?

Comment: Why you give negative band  ?

Comment: The negative votes are explained in the arrow that is clicked: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful)."  There are people that think the question is unclear and doesn't make much sense.  It is poorly formatted and the grammar makes it very difficult to figure out what exactly is being asked.

Comment: now i am not able to ask question as i am blackberry deveopler ..

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot run apps from the app store on the iOS simulator.** The reason for that is that the iOS [*simulator* is not an *emulator*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4544588/643383). The simulator runs on the Intel CPU in your Mac, while apps built for the app store (and for iOS devices in general) are compiled to run on the ARM processor that's in every iOS device. Put another way, the simulator is not binary compatible with iOS hardware.

Comment: please remove your answer]

Comment: There is no way, and why would I remove my answer?

Comment: because every body give negative band ..and I am not able to post question.I want to delete question..:(

Comment: A few downvotes won't hurt, and the answer may help others in the future.

Comment: please vote me so that i will post mt question

Comment: @Rohit This best solution is to update your question so it is clear and so it makes sense. People downvoted because your question is too confusing and unclear.