# System Virtualization : Understanding IO virtualization and role of hypervisor

Tags: system, virtual-machine, virtualization, hypervisor

I would like to obtain a correct understanding of I/O virtualization. The context is pure/full virtualization and not para-virtualization.

My understanding is that a hypervisor virtualizes hardware and offers virtual resources to each sandboxed application. Each sandbox thinks its accessing the underlying hardware, but in reality it is not. Instead it is the hypervisor which does all the accesses. It is this aspect I need to understand better.

Let assume a chip has a hardware timer meant to be used by OS kernel as a tick timer. Lets assume that there are 2 virtual machines (E.g Windows and Linux) running atop the hypervisor.

None of the virtual machines have modified their source code. So they continue to spit out instructions that directly program the timer resource.

What is the role of the hypervisor really here? How are the two OSes really prevented from accessing the real stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of reading, I have reached a certain level of understanding described at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13045437/1163200

I reproduce it wholly here:

This is an attempt to answer my own question.

[System Virtualization : Understanding IO virtualization and role of hypervisor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995768/system-virtualization-understanding-io-virtualization-and-role-of-hypervisor)

## Virtualization

Virtualization as a concept enables multiple/diverse applications to co-exist on the same underlying hardware without being aware of each other.

As an example, full blown operating systems such as Windows, Linux, Symbian etc along with their applications can coexist on the same platform. All computing resources are virtualized.

What this means is none of the aforesaid machines have access to physical resources. The only entity having access to physical resources is a program known as Virtual Machine Monitor (aka Hypervisor).

Now this is important. Please read and re-read carefully.

The hypervisor provides a virtualized environment to each of the machines above. Since these machines access NOT the physical hardware BUT virtualized hardware, they are known as Virtual Machines.

As an example, the Windows kernel may want to start a physical timer (System Resource). Assume that ther timer is memory mapped IO. The Windows kernel issues a series of Load/Store instructions on the Timer addresses. In a Non-Virtualized environment, these Load/Store would have resulted in programming of the timer hardware.

However in a virtualized environment, these Load/Store based accesses of physical resources will result in a trap/Fault. The trap is handled by the hypervisor. The Hypervisor knows that windows tried to program timer. The hypervisor maintains Timer data structures for each of the virtual machines. In this case, the hypervisor updates the timer data structure which it has created for Windows. It then programs the real timer. Any interrupt generated by the timer is handled by the hypervisor first. Data structures of virtual machines are updated and the latter's interrupt service routines are called.

To cut a long story short, Windows did everything that it would have done in a Non-Virtualized environment. In this case, its actions resulted in NOT the real system resource being updated, but virtual resources (The data structures above) getting updated.

Thus all virtual machines think they are accessing the underlying hardware; In reality unknown to them, all accesses to physical hardware is mediated through by the hypervisor.

Everything described above is full/classic virtualization. Most modern CPUs are unfit for classic virtualization. The trap/fault does not apply to all instructions. So the hypervisor is easily bypassed on modern devices.

Here is where para-virtualization comes into being. The sensitive instructions in the source code of virtual machines are replaced by a call to Hypervisor. The load/store snippet above may be replaced by a call such as

```
Hypervisor_Service(Timer Start, Windows, 10ms);
```

## EMULATION

Emulation is a topic related to virtualization. Imagine a scenario where a program originally compiled for ARM is made to run on ATMEL CPU. The ATMEL CPU runs an Emulator program which interprets each ARM instruction and emulates necessary actions on ATMEL platform. Thus the Emulator provides a virtualized environment.

In this case, virtualization of system resources is NOT performed via trap and execute model.

Comment: +1 for re-mentioning the answer again.