# emu8086 - assembler not responding on startup

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am taking a course in assembly and computer architecture. It is required that we download [software called emu8086 - assembler](http://www.emu8086.com/files/emu8086v408r11.zip), I downloaded the required software, but when I launch it, it just won't respond. It stays in the not responding state for a few minutes and then I have to terminate through the task manager.

I am using Windows 8.1 (64 bit), but all the other people on the course (we were all given the exact same computers) were able to run the software.

Just to make sure you know I reinstalled the software several times and it did not help.

I know that the emu8086 cannot run along other VMs at the same time, and I do have VMware installed on my computer, could it be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried to run the software in the console?

Comment: You should be able to ask the instructor for help getting the software required for the course to work properly. This is not really a programming question.

Comment: Where exactly did you download it from?  There's not enough information in the question for anyone to reproduce exactly what you're doing.  Include the download URL, the filename, and MD5 / SHA1 or some other hash of the file contents.

Comment: @PeterCordes I added the information you suggested.

Comment: @CodyGray The instructor is also clueless why this is happening, I was hoping the stackoverflow community would know.

Comment: *I know that the emu8086 cannot run along other vm's at the same time*  What makes you think that?  From what I can google, it doesn't use hardware-assisted virtualization.  It just emulates, so it doesn't conflict with a hypervisor like VMWare.  ([this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044978/full-emulation-vs-full-virtualization) might have some relevant answers).  i.e. it's just an ordinary user-space program that runs unprivileged instructions and shows graphics on the screen.  It doesn't try to take advantage of the host also being x86 in any compatibility-limiting way, AFAIK.

Comment: Anyway, removed my downvote since you linked the download URL.  I've never used emu8086 (and don't even run Windows, and have very little interest in 16-bit DOS), but maybe it's answerable now for someone that does know more about emu8086.

Comment: I have EMU and VMPlayer and both work great. Reinstall Windows.