# Simple Eclipse based Android project won't launch - no errors

Tags: android, eclipse

Running Eclipse Kepler SE on Mac OSX 10.9 with Java version  "1.6.0_65"

Using SDK manager I have all the following installed
SDK Tools, 
Platform-tools
Build-tools installed
SDK Platform for 4.4

Created a bare bones 'Android Application Project' from the menu

Minimum SDK API 8 Android 2.2 Froyo
Target SDK API 18
Compile with API 19:Android 4.4

Create Blank Activity, no navigation

Right click the project in Project Explorer and run as 'Android Application'

I see activity bar in lower right 'Launching test 100%' for a few seconds and then
Nothing happens!

Is it possible something is configured wrong in my Eclipse installation?

Not sure if it is related but also if I try and manually start the emulator I created in the Virtual Device manager I get the following error

```
emulator: ERROR: no search paths found in this AVD's configuration.
Weird, the AVD's config.ini file is malformed. Try re-creating it.
```

The only lint warning I get is 'not targeting latest version of Android; compatibility modes apply'

What i tried

doing a Project>Clean and also Android Tools>Fix project properties.

modifying my eclipse.ini file with these settings

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms80m
-Xmx2048m
```

rebooting
creating a new empty workspace

Comment: did you launched any emulator?

Comment: yes, created a new one and it starts fine from the Virtual Device manager

Comment: I enabled LogCat and am seeing these 2 messages 12-15 13:10:53.722: D/dalvikvm(1160): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
12-15 13:10:56.342: D/gralloc_goldfish(1160): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.

Comment: And in the console this warning- [2013-12-15 13:13:14 - test] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front

Comment: Ok, so I think Thats the problem. In my Virtual Device manager under 'Emulation Options' nothing was checked. What is the difference between 'Use Host GPU and 'Snapshot'?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617131/android-why-snapshots-and-gpu-are-mutually-exclusive