# Android emulator cannot run for check "Use Host GPU"

Tags: android

In android studio When check "store a snapshot faster startup" emulator is running, but webview project application cannot run it. again when check "Use Host GPU" emulator cannot run.
how to solve it....

Comment: You quesition is not clean.

Comment: In android studio I cannot run emulator when i checked "Use Host GPU". otherwise emulator is ok. How can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't open them together.

According to doc http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#accel-graphics:

> Caution: Do not select the Snapshot: Enabled option. Snapshots are not supported for emulators with graphics acceleration enabled.

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51739/what-is-snapshot-and-use-host-gpu-emulation-options-for

[Android: why snapshots and gpu are mutually exclusive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617131/android-why-snapshots-and-gpu-are-mutually-exclusive)