# Why does my Android emulator hang so often?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

My Android emulator beachballs on startup almost every time I try to use it. I'm currently using Android Studio 0.2.0 build 130.737825 on OSX 10.8.4. It seems like it will launch into Android once or twice, then if I close and reopen, it hangs on the black screen before the Android splash screen. At this very moment, it's been hung for about 15 minutes. I don't see anything useful happening in Console. And Android Studio is fine. It's just the emulator that hangs.

Comment: Are you closing it and reopening between each run of your app? You can open it at the start of the day (or your dev session), and just leave it in the background (it's recommended). For this question, it could help if you add your system info too (namely ram), and Android SDK version.

Comment: I try not to close it too much. My machine has 8gb of RAM, and I tend to keep an eye on the Activity Monitor for RAM usage. I'm running SDK 22.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android emulator is pretty much unusably slow. I recommend using [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) instead of the emulator. Genymotion runs the android device as a virtual machine, so it's basically like having a real device running. And it's super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Android's emulator is slower than Apple's simulator. you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584617/simulator-or-emulator-what-is-the-difference) to know why. But you can actually enhance the virtual device(x86 not ARM) performance, if you install Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM) which can be found in Android SDK Manager.