# Xcode "Simulator"? Android Studio "Emulator"?

Tags: xcode, android-studio, terminology

Why is the [Xcode Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) called "Simulator" while the [Android Studio Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html) is called "Emulator" when they bot basically do the same.

I'm not really sure if they are both simulators or emualtors. 
Not even after reading this discussion:
[Simulator or Emulator? What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584617/simulator-or-emulator-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: Seems to be a question about language, not programming. Or even about corporate policy. :) Of course I could be wrong about that...

Comment: The "Simulator or Emulator" question is also posted to stackoverflow, so it seems to be the right place to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be more about linguistics (or corporate terminology?) than programming.

Comment: You could be right, my opinion is only an opinion.

Comment: As you wrote an Swift/iOS book, can I hear your opinion on this anyway?

Answer (score -1):

**Emulator**:-
In computing, an emulator is hardware or software that enables one computer system (called the host) to behave like another computer system (called the guest). An emulator typically enables the host system to run software or use peripheral devices designed for the guest system.

Performance Emulators are really slow. Emulating the actual hardware usually makes the software run slower than it would natively.

Example:-   Google's Android SDK

[MORE INFO IN WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator)

**Simulator**:-

A mobile simulator is a software application for a personal computer which creates a virtual machine version of a mobile device, such as a mobile phone, iPhone, other smartphone, or calculator, on the computer. This may sometimes also be termed an emulator.
[MORE INFO IN WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_simulator)

Faster than emulators

Example :-Apple's iOS Simulator

Comment: Yes,more a single line.
An emulator can replace the original for 'real' use. A simulator is a model for analysis.