# Is using static bytecode analysis to determine all the possible paths through a given method a variant of trying to solve the Halting Problem?

Tags: static-analysis, bytecode, cil

Is it possible to determine all the possible execution paths by reading the bytecode of a given method, or will that be equivalent to trying to solve the halting problem? If it can't be reduced to the halting problem, then how far can I go with static analysis without crossing the boundary of trying to solve the halting problem?

Related question: ["Finding all the code in a given binary is equivalent to the Halting problem." Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299576/finding-all-the-code-in-a-given-binary-is-equivalent-to-the-halting-problem-re)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is easily equivalent to solving the halting problem.  Consider the following if statement:

if (TuringMachine(x)) then goto fred;

OK, is it *really* possible to goto fred?  You can only answer this question if you can analyze a Turing machine.
There's an equivalent set of bytecodes for this.

Now, if the only problem is to determine all *plausible* paths, and you don't care if you get some false positives, the answer is No.  Consider the following program:

```
if (false) then x else y ;
```

The possbile paths:  eval(false);do x  and eval(false);do y  is a complete enumeration.

You have to treat loops specially, as zero, one, two, or some maximum bounded number of iterations, it you want a computable answer.  If a loop can repeat forever, some of your paths will be infinitely long and you can't report them with a algorithm and finite time :-{