# GBA emulator wp7 in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, emulation, gameboy

I want to do a GameBoy Advance emulator for WP7 but I'm not sure where to start. Anyone can point me in the right direction? I know there is one for GB, maybe starting there would be a good idea. Any libraries or resources?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448673/how-do-emulators-work-and-how-are-they-written

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download the source for VisualBoyAdvance here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/vba/files/VisualBoyAdvance/1.7.2/

It's one of the most well known and reliable GBA emulators and it's written in C++, so it shouldn't be too hard to port over.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to imply that it won't be difficult, just that it could be worse.