# Are there any resources dedicated to emulator development?

Tags: emulation, hardware, device-emulation

I am interested in developing my own emulators but can't find any resources on how to do this.

I have been looking everywhere online and there don't seem to be any websites dedicated to developing emulators.  I have looked on Amazon for books on the subject and nothing relevant comes up.

Does anybody know of any books on emulator development?

Are there any sites dedicated to emulator development (the same way OSDev Wiki is dedicated to operating system development)?

Or is emulation something I find my own way to do depending upon the device being emulated?

Thanks in advance for any help anybody can offer.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Take a look at Virtual Machine bytecode execution, it's the same

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do emulators work and how are they written?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448673/how-do-emulators-work-and-how-are-they-written)

Comment: The first answer to the (closed) duplicate question @GregHewgill links to has a resources section.

Answer (score 0):

I can't provide a ton of hard resources however, check out http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Emulators/Information_and_Papers/

other high level academic and computer science publication would also be good and here's a few interesting reads:

http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=801235

https://archive.org/stream/1988-04-compute-magazine/Compute_Issue_095_1988_Apr#page/n43/mode/2up